# Setting text in Ajax toolkit htmleditorextender on button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, toolkit, htmleditorextender

I have been trying to figure this out for most of a day, so any help will be very very welcome...

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    ChangeText("This is the changed text from the document ready function");
  });

  function ChangeText(newText) {
    var editorControl = $("#txtHTMLEditor");

    editorControl[0].value = newText;
  }

</script>
<div>
  <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
  </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

  <div id="divTemp" style="display: block">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtHTMLEditor" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="25" Width="100%" Text="<b>This is test text</b>" /><br />
    <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="htmlEditorExtender1" TargetControlID="txtHTMLEditor" runat="server" DisplaySourceTab="true">
    </ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
  </div>

  <input type="button" onclick="ChangeText('This is the changed text from the button click event'); return false;" value="Perform Change">
</div>
</form>
```

The above code changes the text in the html editor perfectly in the document ready event, but does nothing if I click the button.

Both events fire the same javascript function (ChangeText()), with the value of the text area being changed in both instances, but the change does not show in the text area in the case of the button click event.

Any ideas why not?

Comment: that should definitely be triggering on the button click. http://jsfiddle.net/maEWb/

Comment: It's more likely that you aren't properly updating the textarea text. Look at it's documentation for javascript interaction for whatever editor that is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the text via the HTMLEditorExtender's client side interface:

```
  function ChangeText(newText) {
    var editorControl = $find("<%=htmlEditorExtender1.ClientID%>");
    editorControl._editableDiv.innerHTML = newText;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Location of the HTML contents of the HtmlEditorExtender may have changed over time. This is how I did it in version 7.1005 of the toolkit.

```
            var htmlSource = $('#<%= DescriptionEnglishEditor.ClientID %>Extender_ExtenderContentEditable').html();
            $('#<%= DescriptionFrenchEditor.ClientID %>Extender_ExtenderContentEditable').html(htmlSource);
```

The key is to locate the object in the DOM that is storing the HTML and reference it correctly.